# Create ConvertTo method or create Convert class to handle convertions

Tags: oop, type-conversion, converters

I have type A which should be converted to type B.
Which is the best way to do it?

1. Create ConvertToB(I think it is better name than a.ToB()) method in A e.g.

   A a = new A();

   B b = a.ConvertToB();
2. Create special type which handles convert operations e.g.

   Converter c = new Converter();

   B b = Converter.AToB(a);

I think about second option because adding ConvertToB in type A breaks single responsibility principle.

On the other hand second option may end up in large Converter type with many methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more to do with Object Oriented Principles namely Information Hiding and Encapsulation. Generally breaking one results in chain of breaking other principles. See how

your option-1 of keeping conversion logic in A results in following code

```
class A {
    private int a1;
    public A(int a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public B convertToB(){
        int b1 = 0; // appropriate conversion from a1
        return new B(b1);
    }
}
```

observe here we **DO NOT need public access** to a1.
Your option-2 of keeping conversion logic in separate converter results in following code

```
class Converter {
    public A bToA(B b){
        int a1 = b.getB1();// Information hiding and encapsulation broken
        //       ---------
        return new A(a1);
    }
}
```

observe here we **DO NEED public access to b1**.
Obviously we encourage client code to use getX() methods and operate on somebody else's data and hence violation of encapsulation.

In my opinion if the conversion logic is not changing then Option-1 (convertToX()) should be used to protect Object Oriented nature. If we need to allow dynamic (run time) conversion logic then option-2 of separate Converter is better.

If A and B are two different presentations of same underlying data then see
[Serialization: Converting from One Class to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470181/serialization-converting-from-one-class-to-another-class/45473556#45473556)